# System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'order'.' C# Desktop Application

Tags: c#, t-sql, exception

I am creating a simple desktop sample for T-SQL but for some reason it throws an exception.
Exception appears at  `int j = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();`

```
DateTime d = DateTime.Now;
String Id = textBox4.Text;
String date = d.ToString();
String quantity = textBox2.Text;
String connectionstring = @"Data Source = (LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB; AttachDbFilename = C:\Users\Junaid Computers\source\repos\WindowsFormsApp3\Softech.mdf;Integrated Security = True";
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionstring);
String query = "INSERT INTO order (CustomerId,OrderDate,OrderQuantity) VALUES('" + Id + "','" + date + "','" + quantity + "')";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
con.Open();

int j = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
if (j > 0)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Data Inserted:");
}
else if (j == 0)
{
    MessageBox.Show("SOrry! No Insertion:");
}
```

Comment: Try `INSERT INTO \"order\"`. The word "order" is a reserved keyword

Comment: Thanks! can't believe I missed that.

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection - check out [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `INSERT INTO \"order\".` The word "order" is a reserved keyword.
This worked for me.